# How to Read stdout from container with another container in same pod

Tags: logging, kubernetes, stdout

I want to read log from container with another container in same pod

i've tried approach that shared volume between two container
so i mapping the log file to a shared volume from container 1
and read the log file from container 2 with the same shared volume

but how i can read the stdout directly ? especially in kubernetes and the same pods ?

Comment: You can access the stdout of containers with `kubectl logs <pod>`. For a specific container in the Pod `kubectl logs <pod> -c <container>`.

Comment: well, that condition if i check it in host.. but i want to check it from side container in same pod..

could we achieve that ?

Comment: Kubernetes stores the stdout and stderr of containers in some file on the node on which the Pod is running. Where exactly this is, depends on your configuration. See [these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47916855/4747193).

Comment: i think i don't configure that much, and where is the default path ?..
my issue is, i want to run a script in a container 2 to read stdout from container 1..
it'll be work or not ?

Answer (score 0):

You should share process namespace between these two containers and then tail the logs of a process in one container to another.

Read the [k8s docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/share-process-namespace/)

Comment: This doesn't address the question. It sidesteps and suggests an alternate scenario. Also, don't link to something without including the relevant bits here, as linkrot will render this answer useless over time.

Answer (score 0):

I've just been exploring this and I think there's two options here:

- If your "logging" container is in the same pod, it looks like you should be able to do it by creating a container with a [shared process namespace](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/share-process-namespace/), then finding the PID of the relevant target process in the (shared) `/proc` from within your logging container, and reading the target process's stdout fd.
- Run a container which mounts in the [node's logs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/logging/#log-location-node) from `/var/log/pods`, then somehow ships off the (relevant) container logs. Then you have to arrange for that container to end up on the right node; either by adding it to your pod, affinities, or running it as a daemonset I guess.