# Where is the log file for `kubectl log pod/yourpod`

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kubernetes-pod

When I type `kubectl log pod/yourpod` to get my pod's logs, behind the scene, k8s must read the log from somewhere in my pod.

What's the default path to the log generated by my container?
How to change the path?

Inside my container, my process uses `sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime/pkg/log` to generate logs.

Comment: i think its the stdout stream

Comment: You can refer old thread on the same https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47915287/where-are-kubernetes-pods-logfiles

Answer (score 2):

It is the console output (stdout / stderr) that is captured by the container runtime and made available by the kubelet running on the node to the API server.

So there is not real log file, though the container runtime usually has a means of buffering the logs to the file system.

Comment: Is it possible to redirect the output to log files, consumed by Splunk or cloudwatch. Is it a stupid idea to do so?

Comment: Yes, that is possible.